# Should informed badge require a quiz to earn

Tags: feature-request, badges

I have noticed that quite a few users (mostly new users - 40 rep or below) do not mark questions as accepted.  It probably isn't as annoying to those with tens of thousands of rep, but I am still low enough that not earning that 15 rep is annoying, especially if I put much time into the answer.  With some of these answers I have upvotes that may have came from the OP, but not the accepted mark.

I hate the idea of posting "Glad to help, please accept this answer if it helped" comments, but I have done that a few times.  One person commented back that "Yes, that answer really solved my problem" (not the exact words), but didn't accept.

I haven't done an exhaustive check of it, but it looks like quite a few of the users have the informed badge as well that indicates that they have read the tour page, but you can earn that badge just by scrolling through it and not reading (which I have never done, not even on the other stack exchange sites... I know about this from a guy I knew in college... really!).

Should there be a short quiz to earn that badge instead of just reading or scrolling through the tour page?  This way people that earn the badge will have actually read the page.

I would expect questions like "Somebody answered your question and completely solved your problem.  What should you do next? A) Accept their answer B) Post a comment saying *Thank you* C) Nothing" where the correct answer is A.

We can also address other behavior that an **informed** user should know better than (excessive commenting, posting comments as answers, writing "My code doesn't work.  I haven't provided anything.  What is wrong?" questions, and so on).

I'm not sure if this would be difficult to implement, and what the rest of the community thinks.  I don't envision anything overly complicated - something that you could run through in 3 to 4 minutes.

Comment: Yeah. You right there are many people i notice who ask and ask but never accept any answer. like this person http://stackoverflow.com/users/5753132/user5753132. But, i think there is no any solution for that type people. Just comment on there post to accept is only one solution.

Answer (score 5):

Users who scroll down only to earn the badge will take the quiz for the *same* reason. I don't think we can guarantee that each and every user will follow the guidelines, no matter method we use (information page, tutorial or quiz).

> I hate the idea of posting "Glad to help, please accept this answer if it helped" comments

You shouldn't hate the idea, it's really acceptable if OP is *new* and *hasn't* accepted any answer yet. What would you do if such a feature exists and OP still didn't give you his shiny "v"? You would still ask him to accept it, no? So in my opinion this feature will give no added value, specially when some users create an account only to ask one question, and once they get an answer, they don't really care about something else.

Comment: Well, I mean for them to pass the hypothetical quiz to earn this badge, not just take it.  We can be reasonably sure that if they passed it, they either read the tour page, or at least reasoned out what behavior we expect.  Which is certainly better than carrying around a badge for not understanding the format.  I agree that we can't force them to follow the format.  But we shouldn't have users who don't even know that you can accept answers, but have a badge saying that they do know that.

Comment: I thought comments like *please accept this answer if it helped* were obsolete and too chatty, all the ones I've flagged have turned out helpful, so now I'm confused.

Comment: @JustDoIt - It's only OK if the user is brand new and has never accepted before because you're explaining how the site works. It's also only OK to do *once* for that user. If the user's been around long enough to know this or has already been told how to accept, any comment asking for an accept is wrong. (It also makes sense to mark as obsolete once the user has accepted an answer.)